# How can I make it so a sprite is always upright?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a 2D topdown Unity project, I'm trying to make it so when the player clicks, a bullet comes out. The shooting is working perfectly, just there is a countdown on the bullet, and when the bullet is shot the countdown is always pointing towards where the player was facing. I'd like to make it so even if the player is facing sideways or up or down, the countdown always remains upright and readable.

Comment: show some code, add some pictures for context.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Comment: pretty impossible to assist with no code posted

Answer (score 1):

Use `World Canvas` and use `transform.lookAt` to face it to your camera.